# Size of htaccess files and IP address allow/deny statements on LiteSpeed server

Tags: .htaccess, hosting

I'm sure this is a very novice question but I am having difficulty with a so-called premium shared business hosting account.

I wanted to limit access to a domain name to a set of four countries and was told by the host to use a specific web site that provides IP addresses by nation/region and add that list to the htaccess file.

The four nations I chose resulted in over 230k `allow for` statements and a 6.2MB htaccess file.  The host's support told me that would be no problem.  However, the site stopped loading as HTTPS after that and it took them all day to tell me that the htaccess file is either too large or takes over 500ms to process.

My questions are:

1. Is allowing/denying IP addresses in this manner feasible? Is it better to secure/limit access to files rather than checking IP addresses.
2. Is there an aggregation methodology that doesn't require a $60 per month subscription. The one I read about claims a 70% reduction, but that would still leave about 70k `all for` statements.

It's just a tiny four-page site but, in about the first half-hour of being live, IP addresses from China, Russia, Honduras, Romania were scanning through the files.  I don't know much about this area but it's easy to determine they weren't navigating within the web pages but were looking for databases and PHP files.

I should add that I'm not implying everyone in these countries are a problem.  We don't sale or ship our product outside the four countries selected and it seems to make sense to block the rest to limit these issues.

Thank you.

Comment: Why on earth would one want to block requests from a specific country?!? A resolution per IP address is _not_ precise! You will block legitimate users. Or users forced to use special network setups. The fact that someone scans your pages is just fine, your page has to be robust anyway. You cannot gain security by blocking certain IP address ranges.

Comment: Initially at the suggestion of the host.  Also because there's no reason to make the site available in locations where we don't sell or ship our product. For example, why does a local barber shop or restaurant in a town need to have a web site listed across the globe?  There is a web site that provides the IP addresses for this task.

Comment: Why, as you put it, can security not be gained by blocking IP addresses?  There obviously are problems in every nation but if one can limit the number of nations that significantly limits the "bad" traffic.

Comment: Who says that there is not person traveling to the town where your local barber shop is located, thinking of calling the barber? Because he is a regular customer coming home from a trip? Or someoe doing a leasure trip to that place thinking of having a great evening in that local restaurant, tries to reserve a table, but which won't be possible now since you blocked his IP address?

Comment: The tool you are using is like a sledge hammer used to do ivory carving. Sure, you can do that, but it is not exactly a sign of good craftsmenship, so not exactly an advertisement for your consultancy quality.

Comment: Maybe using [GEOIP](https://www.litespeedtech.com/support/wiki/doku.php/litespeed_wiki:config:geolocation) method to redirect/block those countries is easier for you?

Comment: @Eric Thank you for the idea.  I'm not sure I can do that since this is a shared hosting account but I will read through it to determine if that is true.